# Insert include PHP file in to html table

Tags: php, html, html-table, include

I wondered if anyone had any ideas how I could call and run a PHP script in an upper row or cell in this table. This is the code I have:

```
foreach ($result_array as $category_link){
        if ($counter == $number_of_categories_in_row){  
            $counter = 1;
            $result_final .= "\n</tr>\n<tr>\n";
        }
        else $counter++;

        $result_final .= "\t<td>".$category_link."</td>\n";
    }

    if ($counter) {
        if ($number_of_categories_in_row-$counter){
            $result_final .= "\t<td colspan='".  ($number_of_categories_in_row-$counter)."'>&nbsp;</td>\n";
        }

        $result_final .= "</tr>";
    }
}
```

The code I would like to run in a row or cell is

`include ("slideshowimages.php");`

I cant seem to get the file to run when in the table. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are attempting to insert that file? What happens when you run the code?

Comment: If the filename of the HTML page does not have a `.php` extension the php interpreter will not be invoked and the PHP code will not run

Comment: I've made some small changes to your code. Avoid using things like `if (condition) action()` because it can be unclear what's part of a certain block. Always use `{ }` to enclose blocks, even if they're just a single line, and your code will be less prone to accidental bugs.

Comment: hi thanks m1ke the php code I am trying to run in the table

Comment: <?php
    $directory = 'slideshow_images';  
    try {     
 // Styling for images 
 echo "<div id=\"myslides\">"; 
 foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {   
  if ($item->isFile()) {
   $path = $directory . "/" . $item; 
   echo "<img src=\"" . $path . "\" />"; 
  }
 } 
 echo "</div>";
    } 
    catch(Exception $e) {
 echo 'No images found for this slideshow.<br />'; 
    }
    ?>

Comment: I would like to run the above code a before result final within the code block shown   klein